# Java continuous thread execution is getting delayed the task (Any other alternative)

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

Am using thread for to perform some tasks. This task will be executed with random interval of ~10 seconds. Also this code will be runner for entire day. The problem is after 2 to 3 hours of execution, the task execution time is getting slower than current time (approx 10 minutes slower).

Consider, if am executing this program for a month, then delay will be more than current time. Any other solutions for this.

**code snippet:**

```
long currentTimeStampEntry = 0;
long prevTimeStampEntry = l_utc_SystemTimestamp;

if (isValidEntryFound) {
    do {
        currentTimeStampEntry = Long.parseLong(cuurentRow[0]);
        interval = (int) (currentTimeStampEntry - prevTimeStampEntry);
        prevTimeStampEntry = currentTimeStampEntry;
        mlogger.info(TAG + " Sleeping for " + interval + " secs");
        Thread.sleep(interval * 1000);
        commHandler.sendData(cuurentRow);
```

Comment: You should not use `Thread.sleep`. You should use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Other than that, it's not entirely clear what your code is supposed to do... maybe post a [mcve]?

Comment: Your code accumulates the errors that sleeping has + you ignore the time `commHandler.sendData(cuurentRow);` and the other code needs to execute. Your code should therefore run too slow. It's basically guaranteed to drift away if you never check against a clock. Rather use the actual current time to calculate how long you need to sleep (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis()`). I don't know how your code is supposed to work so I don't know where / how you need to include it.

Comment: For a simple schedule like this @daniu is right, a `ScheduledExecutorService` would probably be a good way to go. For complex schedules you'd want to use a scheduler library, such as Apache Quartz. The reason your schedule drifts is because you're not really delaying for just 1000ms, you're delaying for 1000ms **PLUS the time it takes your code to run** and that adds up over time. So if you have the code you run in a separate thread from your delay (like a `ScheduledExecutorService` does), then it would be better.

Comment: Additionally, if you ever want to use more complex schedules, like: "run every weekday at 3am as long as it's not a holiday", then I would recommend using a scheduler library such as [Apache Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq.html#FAQ-whatQuartz). But for simple delayed repetition definitely use `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is it for Fixed interval? In my sceanrio, interval is random